# Table.TransformColumns based on a partial Header

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table where each client has a DATA column and a RETURN column and the values in each need to divide by a value. Since i dont know how many clients will be on the source workbook when I get it each month the only constant I have is the DATA (m) and RETURN headers.

I am attempting to divide every column where its header has "DATA (m)" in the title. Because the original headers were the client names, i have transposed the table, swapped the columns and re transposed the data to switch around 2 rows. Then I have promoted the "DATA (m)" and "RETURN" to the headers -which since there are 1 per client; adds a suffix to avoid duplicate headers. 
I just need a way to complete a transform columns based on the prefix of each header.

```
#"DATADivide" = Table.TransformColumns (#"Transposed Table1", {{"DATA (m)", each _ / 1000, type number}})
```

I would like that the values in column "DATA (m)" to divide by 1000 (and the same code can be duplicated to work on Return) for every instance where that phrase appears in the header.

Many thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This divides all columns with column names containing "Data (" by 1000

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
ColumnList = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each Text.Contains(_, "Data (")),,
Divide= Table.TransformColumns(Source, List.Transform(ColumnList, each {_, (inner) => inner / 1000, type number}))
in Divide
```

Comment: Hi - thank you for the response, could you explain your steps in a bit more detail? My objective is for the step to amend all columns where the header begins with "Data (m)" without having to perform transform on each one (as there may be more columns added/removed from the original document). Perhaps im missing some understanding of the logic though...

Comment: Step 2 = get all column names that start with "Data (" as a list      Step 3 - transform all columns on that list by dividing by 1000 in a single step